# Pros and Cons of multiple region databases

Tags: database-design, architecture

Can someone tell me pros and cons of using multiple region databases? I am working on an application which would be mostly used in one particular region but may be rarely used in different regions as well. So, I am thinking that should I make my application multi-region or not? That's why asking about pros and cons.

Comment: do you mean single tenancy?

Comment: sorry  i did not get what is single tenancy?

Answer (score 0):

With "regions", I'm assuming you're referring to the requirement of your database to support multiple language/locale formats etc. If that's the question than I strongly recommend the use of NoSQL databases as they offer flexible schema of the objects which you can use to store data in different languages/locale settings. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `region_id` in your user table and add `user_id` as foreign key in  all tables where data inserted or updated. So when each user login you can distinguish to which region this user belong.